# SWIG: Python list to uint32_t *?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm trying to work with a Python module that was generated by SWIG.  There's a C++ class defined that works like this (simplified):

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Thing
    {
    public:
        Thing();
        ~Thing();

        bool DoSomething(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z, uint32_t *buffer);
    };
};
```

When I try to call it from Python, I get an error about the last argument needing to be of type 'uint32_t*'.  Normal Python integers work just fine for the other arguments, so I can't understand why a list of ints wouldn't work for the buffer.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter to `DoSomething` is a *pointer to* `uint32_t`, not `uint32_t`.  So unlike the other parameters, the function expects to receive a pointer to an integer or an array of integers (since arrays can be used wherever pointers are expected).

I suspect in this case (because it's called 'buffer') that the function expects an array.  You should take a look at the SWIG documentation on [Unbounded C arrays.](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn48)